# Strange behavior in collapsing toolbar Android

Tags: android, material-design, android-recyclerview, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, coordinator-layout

I'm getting familiar with the Android material design and I'm trying to make a simple project that implements a collapsing toolbar based on the scrolling of a recyclerView. The project consists only in one activity with its layout wich contain the reciclerView. I think I did the necessary to implement this animation correctly. The problem is when scrolling, the background of the status bar (The stronger color) disappears and the toolbar overlaps the status bar instead of hidding completely. I'll add the images and code to give you an idea. Thanks in advance, I'll appreciate your help.

[Toolbar before collapsing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlOMb.png)

[Toolbar after collapsing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ar3qT.png)

This is the MainActivity layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvComments"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#333333"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is the build.gradle file where i added the dependencies

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
       applicationId "com.example.francisco.recycler"
       minSdkVersion 19
       targetSdkVersion 23
       versionCode 1
       versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),           'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0'
}
```

And finally if it's needed the MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView  rvComments;
private List<Comentario> commentsList;
private CommentsAdapter adapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    rvComments = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvComments);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    // Data Arraylist
    commentsList = new ArrayList<>();
    commentsList.add(new Comentario(1, 1, 1, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. ", null, "Name", "LastName", " ", "Telematics Engineer", null));
    commentsList.add(new Comentario(1, 1, 1, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. ", null, "Name", "LastName", " ", "Telematics Engineer", null));
    commentsList.add(new Comentario(1, 1, 1, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. ", null, "Name", "LastName", " ", "Telematics Engineer", null));
    commentsList.add(new Comentario(1, 1, 1, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. ", null, "Name", "LastName", " ", "Telematics Engineer", null));
    commentsList.add(new Comentario(1, 1, 1, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. ", null, "Name", "LastName", " ", "Telematics Engineer", null));
    commentsList.add(new Comentario(1, 1, 1, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. ", null, "Name", "LastName", " ", "Telematics Engineer", null));
    commentsList.add(new Comentario(1, 1, 1, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. ", null, "Name", "LastName", " ", "Telematics Engineer", null));


    // Setting the adapter
    adapter = new CommentsAdapter(this, commentsList);
    rvComments.setAdapter(adapter);
    rvComments.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));


    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

I've downloaded a project from the web with this effect and it works fine but I can't see whats wrong with mine.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you solve that somehow?

Answer (score 0):

try adding

android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

in the AppBar and Toolbar